# Cómo resolver el error Function name must be a string in?

Tags: php

El error dicta

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\servidor\htdocs\agregarempleado.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\servidor\htdocs\agregarempleado.php on line 4"

y mi código con error es este:

```
if(!empty($_POST('empleado_nombre'))&& !empty($_POST('empleado_edad')))
```

Comment: Estás usando () cuando en un array tienes que usar []. Por eso te lo interpreta como una función. Cambia $_ POST() por $_POST[]

Comment: gracias, ya funciona!

Comment: Revisa en este enlace: https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php sobre la sintaxis

Comment: Prueba asi: `if(!empty($_POST['empleado_nombre']) && !empty($_POST['empleado_edad']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo comentan no se hace uso de () cuando manejas comparas variables tipo $_post o $_GET se utilizan [].

Existe otra forma de comprobarlo, es utilizando la funcion `Isset()`. La sintaxis para una simple validacion seria.

```
if (!isset($_POST['empleado_nombre'] && N comparacione...)) 
{
   echo "Variable definida!!!";
}else{
  echo "Variable NO definida!!!";
}
```

Cabe destacar que `Isset()` determina si una variable está definida y no es NUL y el `Empty()` etermina si una variable está vacia.

Comment: ahora lo pruebo amigo!

Comment: funciono tambien con la funcion que me aconsejaste usar istvan, gracias!!

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para colocar una un poco mas acercada, hay muchas formas de hacerlo tambien puede ahcerlo sin funciones de php y simples comillas $_variable=' '; ahi es cuestion de gustos y lo que necesites claro.

Comment: En general, cuando uno está usando un array, se usan corchetes, no es el tipo de variable o algo esotérico. Termina de aclararlo para los que vengan más adelante con la misma duda

Comment: Eso no lo sabia llevo bastante sin usar php  por gusto personales, editare mas mi respuesta en cuento pueda, vale ? Gracias por compartir el conocimiento.  @Alfabravo